# object.create doesnt use my new value

Tags: javascript

I've recently found out about object.create and is now trying to understand it.
But I'm not getting it to use my new values I've added after `var person2`.
My first three functions are working great.

```
   var person = {}

person.print1=function(){
    this.firstName="Albert"
    return "My name is "+this.firstName+"."
};

person.print2=function(){
    this.lastName="Einstein";
    this.nationality="Germany";
    return "My name is "+this.firstName+" "+this.lastName+" from "+this.nationality+"."
}

    person.born=new Date("1879,03,14");
person.print3=function(){   
    return person.print2()+' I was born '+person.born.getFullYear()+".";
}
```

This part is where I get confused and unsure of how to use `Object.create`

```
var person2 = Object.create(person);
person2.firstName="Isaac";
person2.lastName="Newton";
person2.nationality="England";
person2.born=new Date("1643-01-04");
```

I use `person2.print3();` to print my details.
My understanding so far is that I don't need a new function to call this?

I get the result: `"My name is Albert Einstein from Germany. I was born 1879."` Which is the same I get from `var person`

But it should be `"My name is Isaac Newton from England. I was born 1643."`

Comment: You may want to look into reading up on the language, I recommend [Douglas Crockford's JavaScript articles](http://javascript.crockford.com/) it gives a pretty solid introduction. Especially [Coding Style](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and [Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) should be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `person2.print3` function your are accessing `person.print2()`.so it will always return `person object`'s values.change that to `this.print2()` to get values of object,from which you are calling the function.changes to `print2` and `print3`

```
person.print3=function(){   
  return this.print2()+' I was born '+this.born.getFullYear()+".";
}

person.print2=function(){
   //this.lastName="Einstein";
   //this.nationality="Germany";
   return "My name is "+this.firstName+" "+this.lastName+" from "+this.nationality+"."
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I get the answer "My name is Isaac Einstein from Germany. I was born 1643."

Comment: there is another bug. in `print2` function you are assigning `this.lastName="Einstein";`. so `person2.lastname` is changed to `Einstein` when you call `this.print2()`. i have updated the answer

Comment: Yes that solved it. But it broke `var person` instead.

Comment: add `person.lastName="Einstein";` and `person.nationality="Germany";` to your code in global scope.

Comment: Yes! That solved it. Thanks, I didn't think about adding them into the global scope! :)

Answer (score 0):

In `person.print3` you're closing over the `person` variable - you're not using this but instead referring to the original person object. Try this:

```
 person.print3 = function () {   
     return this.print2()+' I was born '+this.born.getFullYear()+".";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call the print3 function, the print2 function is called too and therefore the firstName, lastName, nationality and born fields of the person2 object are overwritten.
You may need to modify the person2.print3() to:

```
person.print3=function(){   
  return "My name is "+this.firstName+" "+this.lastName+" from "+this.nationality+". I was born "+person.born.getFullYear()+".";
}
```

Comment: This works. But it feels like I'm doing the same thing twice. I've thought the point of object.create is to be an efficient way to add new value to an existing string. Maybe I've just been missinformed :)

Comment: split the logic. One function to print and one to assign the values.